# Nodejs package cannot be installed in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04

i am on Ubuntu 22.04
i cannot install nodejs after uninstalling previous node version and i do not know if the source or repo is conflicting.

i got node version 12 installed when i first run this command

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | sudo -E bash -`

later, i wanted version node 18 so i apt-get remove node and  i run this command

`curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -`

after, i run
`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

and now i am getting dpkg-deb errors

`After this operation, 184 MB of additional disk space will be used. Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_18.x jammy/main amd64 nodejs amd64 18.13.0-deb-1nodesource1 [28.4 MB] Fetched 28.4 MB in 44s (641 kB/s)                                               (Reading database ... 213677 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_18.13.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb ... Unpacking nodejs (18.13.0-deb-1nodesource1) ... dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.13.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/include/node/common.gypi', which is also in package libnode-dev 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3 dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_18.13.0-deb-1nodesource1_amd64.deb E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1`)

Answer (score 1):

got the latest node lts version working now using nvm to install the node

i follow this link to install nvm https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

and run

```
nvm install --lts   # *installs the latest lts version*

nvm use --lts       # *Use the latest lts version*
```

check node version to verify if node is installed

```
node -v
```

Comment: This absolutely works for me, thanks! It appears that the npm package does not work on the standard Ubuntu 23.04 at the time of writing. Specifically, this should work if anyone gets something like the following error when attempting to run npm: "node: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnode.so.108: undefined symbol: ares_get_servers_ports". It looks like libnode.so is expecting the symbol "ares_get_servers_ports" inside libcares.so but not finding it.